When a fully faithful functor from a triangulated category to itself will be an equivalence.
Let $T$ be a triangulated category. Suppose $i: T\to T$ is a fully faithful exact functor from $T$ to itself. Moreover, suppose $i$ has left and right adjoint. I wonder whether $i$ will be an equivalence.
My solution is following: since $i$ is fully faithful and has left and right adjoint, $T$ has a semiorthogonal decomposition  $$T=\langle i(T), A \rangle,$$
where $A$ is the orthogonal complement of $i(T)$. I think $A$ should be $0$. But I do not know how to show this rigorously.

As Felix commented, if we do not put any condition for the triangulated category, there exist counterexamples.
However, if $T$ is "nice" enough, $i$ can be an equivalence. For example, if $T$ is the derived category of vector space, then $i$ will be an equivalence. I wonder what kind of conditions can we put such that $i$ will be an equivalence. For example, how about $T:=D^{b}(X)$ is the derived category of projective  smooth variety $X$.

I think you might need some essential surjectivity, respectively noetherianess. I feel like one otherwise should be able to include a triangulated category into itself. Similar to $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ via $x \mapsto 2x$. A pathological counter example could be the countable product of a triangulated category with induced triangulated structure and then doing the same thing as in $\mathbb{Z}$

@Felix: Hi, I think you are correct. There exists counterexample. How about this question, what can of condition can put for the triangulated category, such that $i$ will be an equivalence.

I am not sure what you mean by variety (there exist different generalities). However, if you consider derived categories of smooth projective finite dimensional scheme Orlov theorem might help. However, it does not give equivalence yet, so I would be very careful. Weird things tend to happen.

Yes. The variety is just a smooth projective finite dimensional scheme. I also worried that wired things will happen. But I can not give counterexample. Also, I can not prove the statement.

In the book by Huybrechts on Fourier-Mukai transforms there is a good treatment of that situation, maybe that can help you. I am afraid though you might need some assumptions on the base field, respectively the variety

Thanks! I will check it. If you have more ideas, please let me know!

Isn't this the same thing as an orthogonal decomposition of $T$?
